# RelayContainer: Expected record data for prop

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay

So my component looks like this:

```
<ComparePageItem
     key={i} id={i}
     aggregations={aggregations}
     seriesCatalog={seriesCatalog}
     emoMetrics={emoMetrics}
     airings={airings}
     emotionCounts={emotionCounts}
     onSelect={this.optionSelected}
     setVariables={this.setVariables} />
```

but I'm getting this error message:

Warning: RelayContainer: Expected record data for prop `airings` on `ComparePageItem`, but it was instead on prop `emoMetrics`. Did you misspell a prop or pass record data into the wrong prop?

The error seems to imply I'm passing airings data to the wrong property but I can't see how that is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do the fragments of `airings` and `emoMetrics` look like? Did you find the values of `airings` and `emoMetrics` null?

Comment: Yes `airings` is null until certain options are selected making the `airings` data available. `emoMetrics` is and will never be null. Prior to adding `emoMetrics` to the component this error was not happening and `airings` was still null pending certain interactions on the page.

Comment: Also, `airings` is data being returned from Relay, `emoMetrics` is not. `emoMetrics` is just data maintained in state. `airings` when not null, is a Relay object, `emoMetrics` is always an array of objects.

Comment: I suspect that you copied data for `emoMetrics` from `airings`. That's how `emoMetrics` and `airings` might point to the same [fragment pointer](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/59faf32b9eb11f53f8e86ea794593a388417ecbd/src/container/RelayContainer.js#L670-L694).

Comment: No unfortunately there is no overlap between the two props. `airings` is an object returned from Relay or null when no query is found. `emoMetrics` is an array I built in the constructor.

Comment: Did you define any fragment for `emoMetrics` in `ComparePageItem`? Can you give more details about `emoMetrics`? May be snippets of code?

Comment: emoMetrics: [
        {
          id: 0,
          text: 'love'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'hate'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          text: 'crazy'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          text: 'excited'
        },
      ]
  fragments: {
    root: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Root {
        compare {
          airings(program_id: $program_id, network: $network) {
            ${ComparePageItem.getFragment('airings')}
          }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: i wasn't able to format the last comment but you should be able to see that `airings` is a Relay object and `emoMetrics` is just an array of objects. they are not related in any way shape or form. the data returned from Relay wouldn't be in that format nor does the data have anything to do with `emoMetrics`